# Is the expression "ad nauseam" commonly used?

Tags: expressions

I would like to know if the expression can be used commonly or whether it would sound affected or out of place if not used in the appropriate context.

Answer (score 2):

*Ad nauseam* which means going on and on about something to a sickening extent and should be used if something does go on and on and on to a sickening extent though being told not to go on and on to a sickening extent and despite that does go on and on to a sickening extent...

But of course, there is a limit to everything, especially if it is Latin and pompous when a simpler phrase of annoyance may suffice.